# Is there a way to get tasks in Activiti process definition without creating a process instance?

Tags: java, activiti

I have to expose the Activiti API process using a service of my project.

*My requirement is as under*:

I want to know the details about Tasks in Activiti Process Definition, using Java, before running the Process, ie. before creating the Activiti ProcessInstance. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have gone through the Java docs and User guide of Activiti API lots of times but couldn't find a way.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the getBpmnModel(processDefinitionId) method available in the RepositoryService interface.

The result is a Pojo that you can use in o order to introspect the process. The initial pojo represents the model, which can have multiple Processes (but usually only one). From a given Process, you can find all tasks using the findFlowElementsOfType(Class type).

For instance, this snippet should get you a list of UserTasks in a process (not tested but should give you an idea of what is needed):

```
BpmnModel model = processEngine.getRepositoryService().getBpmnModel(someProcessId);
List<Process> processes = model.getProcesses();
List<UserTask> userTasks = new ArrayList<>();
for( Process p : processes ) {
     userTasks.addAll( p.findFlowElementsOfType(UserTask.class))    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. I have another question related to it, Is there a way to update/remove this process from BpmnModel?

Comment: I´ve never used it, but the DynamicBpmnService seems to be a good startting point to look at if you need to manipulate a process definition. There is no docs on it, though, so you´ll have to go through the source code in order to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, one more thing, If I add a process to a BpmnModel, is there a way to deploy only that process and not the entire BpmnModel? And when there are multiple processes in a single BpmnModel, are they individual processes or they are subprocesses?

Answer (score 4):

To access information about the workflow (bpmn) definition, you can do the following:

```
RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
BpmnModel bpmnModel = repositoryService.getBpmnModel(processDefinitionId);
List<Process> processes = bpmnModel.getProcesses();
for (Process p : processes) {
    Collection<FlowElement> elements = p.getFlowElements();
    for (FlowElement element : elements) {
        if (element instanceof UserTask) {
            // do something
        } else if (element instanceof ServiceTask) {
            // do something
        } else if (element instanceof StartEvent) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```